# How many views does the Stack Overflow solution contain?

Tags: discussion, implementation

How many views does the Stack Overflow solution contain? I'm just curious, I want to compare with my MVC web app.

Comment: Solution, as in Kool-Aid?

Comment: 42, of course .

Comment: Are we counting partial views too?

Comment: Sure, partial views can count too... I'm just interested in how many views a crazy popular MVC app like SO contains. In my app, I've been adding a lot more views lately, just like to compare to SO. Thanks!

Comment: @random Solution as in, the visual studio solution.

Comment: It doesn't answer your specific question, but you may be interested in [the FAQ entry on the technologies behind Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10369/131713).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

About 652, as of May 4th 2012.

I might be missing a few, but that's `.cshtml` and the few lingering `.aspx` and `.ascx` files in the main Stack Exchange solution (which includes the APIs but excludes Area 51, StackExchange.com, and Careers).